# rpy2 will not install on a mac Not a directory: '/usr/local/bin/R/bin/R'

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Why will rpy2 noy be installed on a mac?

I mean per the rpy2 docs

```
which R
/usr/local/bin/R


python3 setup.py build --r-home /usr/local/bin/R  install

 raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/usr/local/bin/R/bin/R'
```

This error leaves me nowhere to go

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`RHOME` != "path to the R executable"

Since the R executable appears to be in your `PATH`, you can try instead:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

If you want use an other R, just make it the first one found in the `PATH`.

Should you really want to use the `--r-home` option, it is likely much less tested (if still working), and you should use the path as shown when running the command

```
R RHOME
```